# How to add a shortcut to run all unit tests in project (ST3 + Anaconda)?

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

Or to be more precise, how can i find out which command and which parameters do i need to add in my user .sublime-keymap file to shortcut the `Anaconda: Run Project Tests` command? Are the commands listed somewhere?

This is the default anaconda .sublime-keymap file:

```
[
    {"command": "anaconda_goto", "keys": ["ctrl+alt+g"]},
    {"command": "anaconda_find_usages", "keys": ["ctrl+alt+f"]},
    {"command": "anaconda_doc", "keys": ["ctrl+alt+d"]},
    {"command": "anaconda_auto_format", "keys": ["ctrl+alt+r"]},
    {"command": "anaconda_goto", "keys": ["g", "d"],
        "context":
        [
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.python" },
            { "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": true },
            { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operand": false }
        ]
    }
]
```

The [documentation](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/tests_runner) for the test runner expects me to already know the command i want to shortcut by heart:

> note: Of course you can configure whatever shortcut that you want to
>   run anaconda tests but they are not added by default

Answer (score 5):

See here list all [anaconda commands](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/blob/master/Default.sublime-commands).

#### Answer you question:

Add this in "Prefences->Key Bindings - User"

```
{"command": "anaconda_run_project_tests", "keys": ["ctrl+alt+t"]},
```